# Cypher recommendation query performance

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, r-neo4j

I am working with rNeo4j for a recommendation application and I am having some issues writing an efficient query.  The goal of the query is to recommend an item to a user, with the stipulation that they have not used the item before.

I want to return the item's name, the nodes on the path (for a visualization of the recommendation), and some additional measures to be able to make the recommendation as relevant as possible.  Currently I'm returning the number of users that have used the item before, the length of the path to the recommendation, and a sum of the qCount relationship property.

Current query:

```
MATCH (subject:User {id: {idQ}), (rec:Item),
          p = shortestPath((subject)-[*]-(rec))
WHERE NOT (subject)-[:ACCESSED]->(rec)
MATCH (users:User)-[:ACCESSED]->(rec)
RETURN rec.Name as Item, 
        count(users) as popularity, 
        length(p) as pathLength, 
        reduce(weight = 0, q IN relationships(p)| weight + toInt(q.qCount)) as Strength,
        nodes(p) as path
ORDER BY  pathLength, Strength DESCENDING, popularity DESCENDING
LIMIT {resultLimit}
```

The query appears to be working correctly, but it takes too long for the desired application (around 8 seconds).  Does anyone have some suggestions for how to improve my query's performance?

I am new to cypher so I apologize if it is something obvious to a more advanced user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to consider is specifying an upper bound on the variable length path pattern like this: `p = shortestPath((subject)-[*2..5]->(rec))` This limits the number of relationships in the pattern to a maximum of 5. Without setting a maximum performance can be poor, as paths of all lengths are considered.

Another thing to consider: by summing the relationship property `qCount` across all nodes in the path and then sorting by this sum you are looking for the shortest **weighted** path. Neo4j includes some graph algorithms (such as Dijkstra) for finding these paths efficiently, however they are not exposed via Cypher. See [this page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I implemented the upper bound on the variable length path.  However, I think an issue is the number of ties there are for the shortest path.  Presumably because of this issue, there was little if any impact on performance.  Still a good idea to include it.                          Also, thanks for the link.  I will get to reading